# How to move the cursor into a input text box by clicking a label tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dhtml

How to move the cursor position into a input text box by clicking a label tag?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `for` attribute. No need for any Javascript.

```
<label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
```

The browser will do the magic all by itself.

Comment: `<label>Name <input type="text" name="name" /></label>` would do the thing too :)

Comment: Hi Anpher, that is how the markup structure is currently although this doesn't work...I have a label wrapped around input text field.

I want the cursor to jump to the input text field when I click the label

Comment: FYI: IE6 doesn't support the version without `for`. And the `for` attribute refers to the `id` of the `input` not its `name`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why Yi Jiang's answer wouldn't be working, but it's trivial in jQuery if you prefer to do it that way

```
$('#myLabel').click(function() {
    $('#myTextBox').focus();
});
```